# Is it possible to fire an event on active sheet change?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there an event that fires when the active sheet changes in Google Sheets? Every time the result of `getActiveSheet()` changes, I would like to call a function to update some values within a sidebar I have built to assist navigation in a particularly large Google Sheets Spreadsheet.

Comment: @Phil Reynolds: Have you the solution for this problem?

Comment: @Phil Reynolds: Lol, it has been a loong time, but have you found the solution by any chance ?

Comment: @ManzurKhan See [Trigger when user switches between sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38160116/1595451)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`onSelectionChange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) simple trigger. It will fire whenever a new cell is selected, including when the active sheet changes. (This was [introduced April 22, 2020](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#april_22_2020), well after the original question was asked.)

> The onSelectionChange(e) trigger runs automatically when a user changes the selection in a spreadsheet. Most onSelectionChange(e) triggers use the information in the event object to respond appropriately.

A stringified event object looks like this:

```
{
  "authMode": {},
  "range": {
    "rowEnd": 1,
    "columnStart": 1,
    "rowStart": 1,
    "columnEnd": 1
  },
  "source": {}, // Represents the spreadsheet itself
  "user": {
    "nickname": "NICKNAME",
    "email": "EMAIL"
  }
}
```

This will display a message box whenever the active sheet changes, except on the first run. It also attempts to minimize calls to the PropertiesService as a [quota exists](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas) on it. Note that it uses the sheet ID as they are immutable, unlike sheet names.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  if (activeSheetChanged(e.range.getSheet().getSheetId())) {
      Browser.msgBox(e.range.getSheet().getName());
  }
}

/**
 * Check if the active sheet changed.
 * Will give a false positive if no value exists in the properties.
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function activeSheetChanged(newSheetId) {
  const key = 'activeSheetId';
  const cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  let properties;
  const savedSheetId = getSavedSheetId();
  if (savedSheetId != newSheetId) {
    saveSheetId(newSheetId);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
  
  /**
   * Get the saved sheet ID from the Cache/Properties.
   * @returns {Number}
   */
  function getSavedSheetId() {
    let savedSheetId = cache.get(key);
    if (savedSheetId == null) {
      properties = getProperties();
      savedSheetId = properties.getProperty(key);
      cache.put(key, savedSheetId);
    }
    return cache.get(key);
  }
  
  /**
   * Save the sheet ID to the Cache & Properties
   */
  function saveSheetId(sheetId) {
    properties = properties ? properties : getProperties();
    properties.setProperty(key, sheetId);
    cache.put(key, sheetId);
  }
  
  /**
   * @returns {PropertiesService.Properties}
   */
  function getProperties() {
    return PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To execute a code when switching between different sheets you can use [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee). For example, the following is a general code template to execute a code when switching to **Sheet1**:

```
  function onSelectionChange(e) {
      
    const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
      if (as.getName() == 'Sheet1'){ 
        // put your code here
      }
    }
```

In this way, every time you **select** a different sheet, the `onSelectionChange(e)` **fires** and **the active sheet changes**. Then you can use the active sheet within an if condition to execute a code block of your choice.