# Trigger when user switches between sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Is there a way on to run a script whenever the user switches between sheets in a Google Sheets Spreadsheet?

More or less like `onOpen`, but instead of running when the document is opened, it should fire every time the user switches to another sheet.

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91812/how-can-i-trigger-a-function-when-switching-sheets-within-a-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: On [April 2020](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#april_22_2020) Google added [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) which could be used to check if the user switched between sheets aka tabs.

---

At this time there isn't a trigger related to switch for one sheet to another. To learn about the available triggers in Google Apps Script, please checkout [Triggers and events - Google Apps Script  Guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)

As a workaround you could a custom menu to and `SpreadsheetApp.setActivesheet` to switch between sheets by using a script instead of using tabs and including in that script a call to the function to be run when switching from one sheet to another.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my work-around for onSheetChange:

```
function saveActiveSheet() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var actsheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    // The onSelectionChange() function executes in a separate thread
    // which does not use any script global variables, so use the
    // PropertiesService to maintain the user global state.
    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    userProperties.setProperty('ACTIVE_SHEET', actsheet.getSheetName());
}

function onSheetChange(e) {
    // Do anything needed after a new sheet/tab selection

}

function onSelectionChange(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    // Get current sheet name and compare to previously saved sheet
    var currentactsheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var currentactsheetname = currentactsheet.getSheetName();
    var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var actsheetname = userProperties.getProperty('ACTIVE_SHEET');
  
    if (currentactsheetname !== actsheetname) { // New sheet selected
        saveActiveSheet();
        onSheetChange(e);   // Call custom sheet change trigger
    }
    // Do anything needed when a different range is selected on the same sheet
    else {
        var range = e.range;

    }
}

function onOpen(e) {
    saveActiveSheet();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a "**Feature request**" to implement "onSheetChange" trigger at google issue tracker. You can star it, so google now you want this:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72140210

And here is related question with possible workaround: [How to capture change tab event in Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506382/how-to-capture-change-tab-event-in-google-spreadsheet/48318897#48318897)

Comment: The referred post was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution is 1) faster than the other existing answers, including because it only calls the `getName` API (which takes xxx ms) once per run, 2) uses newer ES2015 syntax supported by Google, 3) uses consistent naming, and 4) uses the spreadsheet from the event argument instead of making a separate API call to retrieve it. Just put your code into `onSheetOpen`.

```
function onSheetOpen(spreadsheet, sheet, sheetName) {
    // Do anything needed after a new sheet/tab selection
}

function storeActiveSheet(name) {
    // onSelectionChange() executes in a separate thread which does not use
    // script global variables, so use the PropertiesService to maintain state.
    PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty('ACTIVE_SHEET', name);
}

function onSelectionChange(e) {
    const {spreadsheet, sheet, sheetName} = eventSpreadsheetVariables(e);
    const userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    const storedSheetName = userProperties.getProperty('ACTIVE_SHEET');
    if (storedSheetName !== sheetName) {
        onSheetOpen(spreadsheet, sheet, sheetName);
        storeActiveSheet(sheetName);
    }
}

function eventSpreadsheetVariables(e) {
    const spreadsheet = e.source;
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    const sheetName = sheet.getName();
    return {spreadsheet, sheet, sheetName};
}

function onOpen(e) {
    const { spreadsheet, sheet, sheetName } = eventSpreadsheetVariables(e);
    onSheetOpen(spreadsheet, sheet, sheetName);
    storeActiveSheet(sheetName);
}
```

(Originally submitted as an edit to existing answer but was rejected as deviating too far from the original answer, so submitting separately.)

Answer (score -2):

you can use

```
sheet1.showSheet();
sheet2.hideSheet();
```

Comment: I think he was asking about events, not functions.