# Want to run same script on each active sheets of shared google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to coding and just trying to learn few things starting with Google sheets. I've a sample script that run on one sheet only and it will be shared spreadsheet. Here's my script

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
var sheet =`enter code here` ["Main01"];
var optionList = ["Options"];
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet);
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(optionList);
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2,1,wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();
var firstLevelColumn = 1;
var secondLevelColumn = 2;
var thirdLevelColumn = 3;


//Begins - main functions

function myFunction() {
} //End of myFunction


function onEdit(e) {
    var activeCell = e.range;
    var val = activeCell.getValue();
    var r = activeCell.getRow();
    var c = activeCell.getColumn();
    var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
    
    if(wsName == sheet && c == firstLevelColumn && r > 1 ){
        firstLevelList(val,r);
    } else if (wsName == sheet && c == secondLevelColumn && r > 1 ) {
        secondLevelList (val,r);
      }
} //End of function - onEdit


function firstLevelList(val,r) {
    if(val == ""){
        ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
        ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } //End of inner if statement 
      else { 
        ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(r,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
        
        var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(op) { return op[0] == val });
        var applyList = filteredOptions.map(function(op) { return op[1] });
        var cell = ws.getRange(r,secondLevelColumn);
        
        applyCellValidation(applyList,cell);
      } //End of else statement
} //End of function - firstLevelList


function secondLevelList(val,r) {
    //similar to firstLevelList with next level validation
} //End of function - secondLevelList


function applyCellValidation(list,cell) {
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).setAllowInvalid(false).build();

      cell.setDataValidation(rule);
} //End of function - CellValidation
```

Some tasks I want to achieve from the code -

1. Run script automatically when spreadsheet opened - maybe use onOpen() trigger. How no idea
2. Since it wil be shared spreadsheet, I want script to run for each of the active sheet whenever accesed by any user.

Comment: When you open a spreadsheet -  the active sheet will alwas be the first one (`Sheet1` - if not renamed). This means that a script that detects the active sheet `onOpen` will always detect the first sheet of the spreadsheet. Is it what you want? If you want the script to run again after the user manually changed the active sheet - that cannot happen `onOpen`. Also, currently your script is set up `onEdit` - would you like to maintain this functionality (the script should run both `onOpen` and `onEdit`) or only `onOpen`?

Comment: @ziganotschka I would like to make it work, whenever any sheet tab opened and edited by user. Script to work for all the sheet tabs of spreadsheet in similar manner. Thanks

Comment: In this case you need (in addition to your `onEdit` trigger) an `onSelectionChange` instead of `onOpen` trigger - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

### To detect a change of the active sheet you need to use the `onSelectionChange` trigger

The `onSelectionChange` trigger allows you to estimate either the new selection belongs to the same sheet like the old selection - or to a different sheet.

There is an elegant [implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484569/is-it-possible-to-fire-an-event-on-active-sheet-change/63904510#63904510) developed by [@Diego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329498/diego).

Applying it to your case, you should add to your already existing script the following functions:

```js
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var activeCell = e.range;
  if (activeSheetChanged(activeCell.getSheet().getSheetId())) {
    var val = activeCell.getValue();
    var r = activeCell.getRow();
    var c = activeCell.getColumn();
    var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
    if(wsName == sheet && c == firstLevelColumn && r > 1 ){ 
        firstLevelList(val,r);
    } else if (wsName == sheet && c == secondLevelColumn && r > 1 ) {
        secondLevelList (val,r);
      }
   }
} //End of function 

function activeSheetChanged(newSheetId) {
  const key = 'activeSheetId';
  const cache = CacheService.getUserCache();
  let properties;
  const savedSheetId = getSavedSheetId();
  if (savedSheetId != newSheetId) {
    saveSheetId(newSheetId);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
  
  /**
   * Get the saved sheet ID from the Cache/Properties.
   * @returns {Number}
   */
  function getSavedSheetId() {
  console.log("called")
    let savedSheetId = cache.get(key);
    if (savedSheetId == null) {
      properties = getProperties();
      savedSheetId = properties.getProperty(key);
      cache.put(key, savedSheetId);
    }
    return cache.get(key);
  }
  
  /**
   * Save the sheet ID to the Cache & Properties
   */
  function saveSheetId(sheetId) {
    properties = properties ? properties : getProperties();
    properties.setProperty(key, sheetId);
    cache.put(key, sheetId);
  }
  
  /**
   * @returns {PropertiesService.Properties}
   */
  function getProperties() {
    return PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  }
}
```

Also:

If you want to compare the sheet name to "Main01", you need to change your line 1 from `var sheet = ["Main01"];` to `var sheet = "Main01";` to make your script work.